# beforeCreate function sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

Before storing data to database I must modify string . Here's my code

```
beforeCreate:function(value ) 
{      
    value.text = value.text.replace(/(\t|\n)/g, '');   
}
```

How to add callback to this function? I know that there must participate callback.

Comment: Provide your whole `Model.js` that related to `value.text`. @brittonjb answer should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should do it:

```
beforeCreate: function(values, callback) {      
   values.text = values.text.replace(/(\t|\n)/g, '');
   return callback();   
}
```

You can refer to the [docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html) for more examples.

Comment: Brittonjb thank you for response ) . but it did not change . data are saving without modification (.

Comment: Is the attribute you're trying to change called `text`?